# Can't align bootstrap rows perfectly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't get these bootstrap rows to align properly. I've fiddled with the width, margins and padding and I can't figure out the problem. Any solution or advice to give would be much appreciated.

https://jsfiddle.net/so155kj7/

HTML

```
<header class="container">
        <h1>Projects</h1>
    </header>
    <section class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="tile col-md-3"></div>
            <div class="tileLong col-md-6"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="tile col-md-3"></div>
            <div class="tile col-md-3"></div>
            <div class="tile col-md-3"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="tileLong col-md-6"></div>
            <div class="tile col-md-3"></div>
        </div>

    </section>
```

CSS

```
header {
    text-align: center;
}

#footerRights {
    padding-top: 5px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

.tile {
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    margin: 20px;
}

.tileLong {
    height: 200px;
    background: blue;
    margin: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your columns should add up to 12 instead of 9.

Use this code and change your CSS from 'margin' to padding

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="tile col-md-4">
          <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="tileLong col-md-8">
           <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="tile col-md-4"><div class="inner"></div></div>
        <div class="tile col-md-4"><div class="inner"></div></div>
        <div class="tile col-md-4"><div class="inner"></div></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="tileLong col-md-8"><div class="inner"></div></div>
        <div class="tile col-md-4"><div class="inner"></div></div>
    </div>
```

And here is the CSS you need:

```
header {
text-align: center;
}

 #footerRights {
padding-top: 5px;
font-size: 1.5em;
}

 .tile {
height: 200px;
padding: 20px;
}

.tileLong {
height: 200px;
padding: 20px;
}
.innerLong {
height: 150px;
background-color: blue;
}
.inner{
height: 150px;
background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Remove your margins. If you want padding between your elements then you need to nest new elements within your "tile"s Il update my answer to show you

Comment: So with the div's with the class of inner do I give them padding?

Comment: I just updated my answer. This will solve your problem. You give the outer Divs the padding and the col-md-* so they can retain their width while editing the inner divs as needed. I hope this helps!

Comment: :D :D :D :D :D :D you are now my new idle. Thanks a lot you solved my prob before I had to go to work :D

Comment: Awesome! I went through a lot off trouble with this sort of stuff as well! Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

you should wrap content of your div's with class=col-md-*, below is an example and working fiddlw

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="tile col-md-3">
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tileLong col-md-6">
      <div></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="tile col-md-3">
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tile col-md-3">
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tile col-md-3">
      <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="tileLong col-md-6"><div></div></div>
    <div class="tile col-md-3"><div></div></div>
</div>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0j1ysp8v/)